# How to organize controller directory in rails 4 without messing up routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, namespaces, code-organization, subdirectory

First off... I love keeping things organized.  As such, it's starting to bother me that the list of controllers in my app just keeps growing in one large directory.

Ideally, I could construct a list of subdirectories and organize my controllers.  You can do this with namespaces, but then the subdirectory shows up within the url, and I really don't want this to happen.

Does anyone have a different strategy to keep their controllers, helpers, models, and views organized?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Ideally, I could construct a list of subdirectories and organize my controllers. You can do this with namespaces, but then the subdirectory shows up within the url, and I really don't want this to happen.

You can `scope` the routes against a specific namespace. Read **[Controller Namespaces and Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)**

```
scope module: 'admin' do
  resources :posts, :comments
end
```

Will generate routes at `/posts` while the controller is at `Admin::PostsController` found in `app/controllers/admin/posts_controller.rb`.